# Executing python3 command in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm working on a NLP project using Jupyter Notebook and Python 3.
I use the *spacy* library for lemmatization. I would like to use the spacy 'en' model. In Python, this would be:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

For this to work, I should first download the 'en' model. In command line, this would be:

```
python3 -m spacy download en
```

After doing this in command line, it worked well when executing code in Spyder for instance, but not in Jupyter Notebook.

The **first idea** I had was to use a command like this one in Jupyter Notebook:

```
!python3 -m spacy download en
```

as it is possible to use the exclamation mark to execute *pip* commands in Jupyter Notebook. It did not work out.

The **second idea** I had was to create a cell with this command:

```
% bash
python3 -m spacy download en
```

but it did not work out either.

So my question is: **How can I execute this Python3 command so that the spacy 'en' model is downloaded in Jupyter Notebook too ?**

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. Try this command. I think it will work.

```
conda install -c spacy spacy
```

You can do it manually. Copy all spacy folder from 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages` 
to `C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`.